# Using mv to rename symlinks in php

Tags: php, linux

With this code block, I am able to rename symlinks programmatically in php;

```
$argSource = escapeshellarg($old_name);
$argDestination = escapeshellarg($new_name);
$cmd="mv ".$argSource." ".$argDestination;
    exec($cmd, $retOutputArray,$retValRename);
```

The code works fine when I have whitespaces  in the `$old_name` and `$new_name`.

The problem is when there is totally no whitespace in `$old_name` ;

```
 /srv/www/htdocs/filestorage/somefolder/symlink1     //$old_name - will not    
                                                     //work
```

the renaming will fail and `symlink1` is deleted!

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: What if you try running the commands manually and see what you get, then debug the error?

Comment: Why are you using exec and having to manually fiddle with escaping shell args, when you could just use [rename()](http://php.net/rename)?

Comment: Well, if the command does not work as expected I suggest you dump it instead of executing it to see what the problem is.

Comment: And please use _italic_ type setting instead of shouting all the time by using ALL-CAPS. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Frank -  if i run the command manually from the linux console - it works in all cases

Comment: @Marc B - php rename does not work for symlinks

Comment: What is your source for "php rename does not work for symlinks"? I'm just wondering if it's specific to some older PHP version because it works fine for me.

Comment: @cascaval - my earlier code was with rename. Did not work for symlinks. Note that the symlinks were created via "ln -s arg1 arg2"

Comment: I would then suggest that you re-try use of `rename()` as suggested by @MarcB. As I said, I tested it myself as well, it works and I cannot find any reference stating that it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, still cannot see the debug output of the actual command.

Comment: @arkascha - var_dump(rename($old_name, $new_name)); gives bool(false)

Comment: I asked to dump the content of the _command_, not it's _result_.

Comment: @arkascha - how do i dump rename($old_name, $new_name) ?

Comment: What about `var_dump($cmd);`?

Comment: @arkascha - will do ... rewriting how i get the arguments for the  command

Comment: @arkascha    mv '/srv/www/htdocs/filestorage/somefolder/1-testRepo' '/srv/www/htdocs/filestorage/somefolder/1o-cvcvcvc'

Comment: but if there is some whitespace in the first argument, it works; mv '/srv/www/htdocs/filestorage/some folder/1-testRepo' '/srv/www/htdocs/filestorage/some folder/1o-cvcvcvc'

Answer (score 1):

Putting this as an answer since it won't work as a comment:

@marcozen, uh, yes, rename() works fine on symlinks:

```
marc@panic:~/test$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 marc marc  0 Apr 13 09:41 origfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 marc marc  7 Apr 13 09:41 symlink -> orgfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 marc marc 54 Apr 13 09:40 z.php
marc@panic:~/test$ cat z.php
<?php

var_dump(rename('symlink', 'renamedsymlink'));
marc@panic:~/test$ php z.php
bool(true)
marc@panic:~/test$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 marc marc  0 Apr 13 09:41 origfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 marc marc  7 Apr 13 09:41 renamedsymlink -> orgfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 marc marc 54 Apr 13 09:40 z.php
```

Note that the symlink isn't even valid. `orgfile` doesn't exist (should be `origfile`, and yet it was renamed. PHP couldn't care less that it's a symlink.

Comment: $retValRename = rename($old_name, $new_name) fails with $retValRename FALSE

Comment: so what exactly are in $old_name and $new_name? Remember that both must have full/absolute paths, otherwise PHP will use its current working directory as the base.

Comment: Or, more elegant, you have to take care of the working directory, just as you would with the `exec()` approach.

Comment: paths are full .. starts at /srv/www/htdocs/filestorage/somefolder/symlink1 for the old_name and /srv/www/htdocs/filestorage/somefolder/symlink2 for the new_name ...

Comment: then check for permissions. your script has to have access to all of the intermediate directories, and write permissions on the `somefolders`

Comment: @MarcB - apache owns the folder - wwwrun , www and permissions are rwsrwxr-x

Comment: Guys, pls note that the mv solution works except when there is NO whitespace in the full path of the old name. Rename did not work at all

Comment: well,w hatever it is, it's not mv or rename's fault. it's something about the arguments you're passing in.

Comment: @MarcB - the arguments are passed in as strings, escaped via escapeshellarg in the mv solution.

Comment: @MarcB - Note - I get the $new_name by exploding and imploding some variables to get full_path for $new_name

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that this issue was solved. The key was the fact the the symlink got deleted after the renaming failed.

There was another script that was responsible for the deletion ( not done by me ). That script DID NOT work with whitespace ( parameters not escaped properly) but DID work with paths that had NO whitespace.

Many thanx  to everyone who responded.